# Ubuntu 16.04 will stop detecting WiFi randomly

Tags: wireless

I am using ubuntu 16.04 on my HP laptop. Facing a weird problem with WiFi. The system stops detecting available WiFi randomly and to get them detected again, I suspend the computer and come back. I tried so many remedies as suggested by Ubuntu communities but nothing helped.
**Output of lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:10.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
```

**Output of dmesg | grep -i firmware**
    [    0.013588] [Firmware Info]: CPU: Re-enabling disabled Topology Extensions Support.
[    0.276013] [Firmware Info]: CPU: Re-enabling disabled Topology Extensions Support.
[    0.278386] [Firmware Info]: CPU: Re-enabling disabled Topology Extensions Support.
[    0.280625] [Firmware Info]: CPU: Re-enabling disabled Topology Extensions Support.
[    2.867087] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 50.0.1 / 17!
[   26.570449] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   26.997083] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
[  363.469793] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, try to use APIC500 (LVT offset 0) for vector 0xf9, but the register is already in use for vector 0x400 on another cpu
[  363.469795] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, failed to setup threshold interrupt for bank 4, block 0 (MSR00000413=0xc000000001000000)
[  363.469796] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, try to use APIC500 (LVT offset 0) for vector 0xf9, but the register is already in use for vector 0x400 on another cpu
[  363.469797] [Firmware Bug]: cpu 0, failed to setup threshold interrupt for bank 4, block 1 (MSRC0000408=0xc000000001000000)

Answer (score 0):

I know this happened to me and it's frustrating:
this seemed to help me
go inside drivers and activate the

- Intel micro-code driver

[This is my setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0T9o.png)

another thing `sudo service network-manager restart`
helps mitigate the issue

Comment: But you need to restart Network Manager every time after resuming.

Comment: Did you try the micro-code driver from intel. That solved my issue.
also you could alias it for quicker deployment:  
for example:
`alias nm="sudo service network-manager restart"`

Comment: Activating Intel micro-code driver did not help. But yes, this alias thing is good. Thanks.